# The Web Server Could Not Find the Requested Resource visual studio debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, visual-studio-debugging

### Issue

I have a .net 4.0 Web Application running in visual studio 2012, every time I go to debug the site i'm receiving the following error:

> The Web Server Could Not Find the Requested Resource

---

### What I've tried

I've followed microsoft's website with solutions: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx)

> 1. From a command prompt window, run the following command: `systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ versionNumber \aspnet_regiis -i`
> 2. I've also attempted to remove the .csproj.user files
> 3. Since we use Source Control i've deleted all items, the site and apppool and reconfigured from scratch.
> 4. AppPool is set to allow 32-bit applications

All to no avail...Anyone have a solution that might solve this visual studio debugging nightmare for me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Steps:

1. Close all solutions in Visual Studio
2. open IIS7 (run > inetmgr)
3. Click your top node (computer name)
4. Open the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" option
5. check if your .Net version has the correct restriction (for example, if you're working with 4.0 is should be on "Allowed")

Comment: this solved it for me, thanks...That seems strange to me as i didn't have the issue on VS2010...this is a new box though so maybe it's just one of those bad image issues.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting the same error when i was running the ASP.NET project from the IIS. I resolved this issue by configuring IIS.

1. Go to run
2. type appwiz.cpl and press enter.
3. Look for "Turn windows features on or off" and click on it
4. now windows will open for Turn windows features on or off
5. look for Internet Information service and select that option.
6. go to world wide web service under the Internet Information service branch
7. expand Application development feature
8. Select all the ASP and .net version. and click on OK.
9. now try running the application from asp.net , it will work :)

Comment: I needed to turn on ASP.NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms but a completely different problem.  I had attempted to install Url Scan and it didn't seem to work correctly as I could not find the .ini file to edit settings  within.  I had forgotten that I had installed it, but it appears by default it will prevent debugging from working.

Uninstalling Url Scan solved the issue for me.  To uninstall it I had to right-click on the .msi file and choose Uninstall.  Url Scan did not show up under the "Add or remove programs" section.